# Does miracast work without wi-fi?

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-direct, android-tv, miracast, screen-mirroring

I have zero Internet capabilities at my home. I use my galaxy s6 as my only source of Internet. I would like to mirror my youtube, Facebook, article reading etc on my new insignia tv. Am I able to do this if I buy a miracast dongle for my TV without using any home wifi network?

Answer (score 1):

The quote I got from [here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-note-3/332008-do-i-need-router-use-miracast.html) is as following:

> These Miracast dongles have 'WiFi direct' like this Sony has,
>   therefore you'd not need a router controlled WiFi home network.
>
> But if I had a Note I'd look for a Samsung Allshare dongle, just to be
>   sure

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I read that as well. I can't seem to find a straight yes or no.